# Using coef and summary.lm with robcov in R (extracting p-values)

Tags: r, linear-regression

I can extract the p-values for my slope & intercept from an ols object this way:

```
library(rms)
m1 <- ols(wt ~ cyl, data= mtcars, x= TRUE, y= TRUE)
coef(summary.lm(m1))
```

But when I try the same thing with a robcov object, summary.lm gives me the p-values from the original model (m1), not the robcov model:

```
m2 <- robcov(m1)
m2
coef(summary.lm(m2))
```

I think this must be related to the Warning from the robcov help page,

> Warnings
>
> Adjusted ols fits do not have the corrected standard errors printed
>   with print.ols. Use sqrt(diag(adjfit$var)) to get this, where adjfit
>   is the result of robcov.

but I'm not sure how.

Is there a way to extract the p-values from a robcov object?  (I'm really only interested in the one for the slope, if that makes a difference...)

Comment: What does coef(summary(m2)) give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacking through `print.ols` and `prModFit`, I came up with this.

```
errordf <- m2$df.residual
beta <- m2$coefficients
se <- sqrt(diag(m2$var))
Z <- beta/se
P <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(Z), errordf))
```

Change m2 to another robcov model.

Try it for yourself by comparing the results of `P` to `print(m2)`